# How to Play mp3 file from memory in delphi?

Tags: delphi, mp3

I am downloading a mp3 file from the internet to memory using InternetReadFile. This works great, I can dump the file on disk and then play it, but I want to play the file without dumping it on disk.

Is there a library i can use to achieve this functionality ? Some docs on how to use the library would be useful too.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [BASS Delphi audio library](http://www.un4seen.com/)

On the other side, search for "MP3" on the [3D Buzz site](http://www.3dbuzz.com). They have a very good series of video tutorials that walk you through the creation of your own MP3 player in Delphi using this library.